# having a logo or a graphics in the header or footer or a printout

Tags: printing, headers-footers

I managed to add footers and headers to my document when I print it. But there seems to be no chance to have anything other than text. How can I add a graphics like a logo or an image?

something like:

PageFooters -> {{alogohere, "a2", "a3"}, {"a4", "a5", someimagethere}}

Comment: I would avoid printing notebooks at all costs... notoriously buggy

Answer (score 3):

It seems unnecessarily complicated, but this works for me. First, grab and resize a logo.

```
image = ImageResize[Import["~/Mathematica/Mathematica_8_logo.png"], 50]
```

Define centred footers for left- and right-hand pages.

```
leftPageFooterCenter = 
   Cell[TextData[Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[image]]]], "Footer", 
        CellMargins -> {{Inherited, Inherited}, {Inherited, Inherited}}];
rightPageFooterCenter = 
   Cell[TextData[Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[image]]]], "Footer", 
        CellMargins -> {{Inherited, Inherited}, {Inherited, Inherited}}];
```

Set options for the notebook.

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],
   PageFooters -> {
      {None, leftPageFooterCenter, None},
      {None, rightPageFooterCenter, None}
   }
]
```

Evaluating these and printing the notebook gives the following.

[image: footer image]

Comment: Works! Great. Thanks a lot!